# Change !doctype with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want know and understand, is it possible to change the doctype?
I browsed on google a lot about it but didn't get clear with the point.

I am working in CMS based layout, where I don't have excess to html code. I can just modify the CSS and add scripts to add div's and other html elements.

We are using old doctype in the html coding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Because of this I can't work on latest html5 doctype. 
I want to ask id there anyway I can update the old doctype to html5 doctype?

Need help.

Thanks,

Comment: Regardless of how possible this is, it seems unlikely that this would be a robust solution. Better to figure out how to change this within your cas tool.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.doctype

> doctype is a read-only property

Unfortunately you are unable to modify the doctype.

EDIT: Actually you can. Weird.

```
var doctype = document.implementation.createDocumentType(
    'html',
    '',
    ''
);

document.doctype.parentNode.replaceChild(doctype, document.doctype);
```

Let me know how that works out for you.